# Equivalence between 2 definitions of closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, definition

One of the definition I am using is a set is *closed* if its complement is *open*.

Definition of open set is that for every element in the set, there exists a positive $\delta$ such that the open $\delta$-ball around the element is a subset of the original set.

The other definition is that a set is *closed* if for every convergent sequence $\{a_n\}\in \mathbb{original \space set}$, the limit is also a member of the original  set.

How do I show the equivalence?

Comment: No, your first definition is wrong. Take the set $[0,1)$, which is neither closed nor open.

Comment: What neighborhood of $0$ is in $[0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be open in metric space $X$. Let $C=X\setminus S$, i.e., the complement. Let $d$ be a limit point of $C$. If $d\notin C$, then $d\in S$, which is a contradiction since there is no neighborhood of $d$ that solely contains points of $S$ by the definition of a limit point. Hence $C$ is closed.

To prove the converse, we let $C$ be closed by your second definition in $X$. Hence, $C$ contains all of its limit points. Suppose $S=X\setminus C$ is not open. This means that for some $x\in S$, $\forall \epsilon>0$, there is a point in $C$ that is within $\epsilon$ of $x$.

Let $a_n$ be the sequence of points such that $a_n\in C$ and the distance between $x$ and $a_n$ is less than $\frac1n$. This is a convergent subsequence, so $x$ is a limit point of $C$, a contradiction.

Comment: $\mathbb{R^2}$ is open or closed? By definition 1, it is open. But by definition 2, it is closed too!

Comment: It is both open and closed. As is the empty set.

Comment: But by definition 1 itself (for closed), it is **not** closed. Since its complement is not open.

Comment: That means the definitions are not actually equivalent?

Comment: The complement of $\mathbb R^2$ in the space of $\mathbb R^2$ is $\varnothing$, which is both open and closed. They are equivalent.